How can I find which US graduate programs in math require the GRE General Subject Test and which require the Mathematics Subject Test?
Is there a resource online that can tell me about which schools require the GRE general test versus which schools require GRE Mathematics Subject Test, and which require both?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hmdO7af3-lLvtJQO-szayG6blTvAYBQ1JcYXFZ_6apE/edit?gid=0#gid=0

@user176372 Thanks!

I'm not big on link-only answers, but since this was reopened I'll put this in as an answer.
At time of answering, this resource is fairly current.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hmdO7af3-lLvtJQO-szayG6blTvAYBQ1JcYXFZ_6apE/edit?gid=0#gid=0

Wow, this is helpful. Is there a similar resource for physics?

In case of future link-rot, I've archived this web page at the Internet Archive. At least, I might have. The page shows up and a note indicates that page has "1 capture" (presumably what I just did), but then I'm asked to reload the page, after which it says the page is not saved.
